# Unable to test Open Graph

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create my own actions/objects. When checking with the debugger everything is fine, but when testing with my dev account I get this in my callback:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Is it good or not because I see anything in my timeline, news feed or ticker.

When testing with a test user I get this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Call to a member function on a non-object",
    "type":"BadMethodCallException"
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the call you are using?

Comment: Are you using the test user's access token?

Comment: var token= FB.getAccessToken();
FB.api("/me/[MY_APP_NAMESPACE]:hunt?animal=OBJECT_URL&access_token=" + token, callBackTest);

Comment: you are making GET request that is the problem, you need to make POST request, see my answer hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to make `POST` request to facebook api something like below and make sure you have initialised FB:

```
var opts = {
                animal : OBJECT_URL,
                access_token: token
            };

            FB.api('/me/[MY_APP_NAMESPACE]:hunt', 'post', opts, function(response)
            {

            });
```